# How to get user specific data on a Google Analytics request?

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to create a web app where a user can grant access to her Google Analytics account via OAuth2. After positive response I would like to make a request to that user's GA data (in the real application the request would be made "offline"). But when calling:

```
google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(params, callback);
```

`params` should contain `ids`, which should be a list of "table ID"s from the user. How do I get hold of these IDs? Is it necessary to get this information through another profile-scoped-request?

Code:

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var clientId = '123-123.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var clientSecret = 'abc';
var redirectUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/redirect';

var authRequest = function(req, res) {
  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
  var scopes = [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly' ],
      params = { state: 'some-data', access_type: 'offline', scope: scopes };
  var url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl(params);
  res.redirect(301, url); // will return to "authResult()"
};

var _sampleAnalytics = function(req, res, oauthClient) {
 var params = {
    auth: oauthClient,
    metrics: 'ga:visitors,ga:visits,ga:pageviews',
    'start-date': '2015-06-01',
    'end-date': '2015-06-30',
    ids: ['ga:123456789'] // <== How to get this parameter?
  };
  google.analytics('v3').data.ga.get(params, function(err, response) {
    // todo
  });
};

var authResult = function (req, res) {
  if (req.query.error) {
    return handleError(res, req.query.error);
  }

  var oauth2Client = new OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
  oauth2Client.getToken(code, function(err, tokens) {
    // Now tokens contains an access_token and an optional refresh_token. Save them.
    if(err) {
      return handleError(res, err);
    } else {
      oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
      _sampleAnalytics(req, res, oauth2Client);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, that was simple. I just need to make another call to:

```
google.analytics('v3').management.accountSummaries.list(params, function(err, result) {
// ...
});
```

`result` will contain all the required information.